# Call function draw on mouse click

Tags: p5.js

Is it possible to call the `function draw(){}` in a p5 js sketch when clicking on the canvas?

I would like everything under the draw function to be called when clicking anywhere on the canvas, and not before.

```js
function setup() {
 createCanvas(500, 500);
 frameRate(65);
  background('#ff0a0a'); 
 textSize(60);
text("ART", 370, 250);

};
function draw() {
  noFill();
  var red = random(100);
  var green = random(200);
  var blue =random(230);
  var h = random(height);

  stroke(red,green,blue);
  strokeWeight(8);
  rect(frameCount,h,300,20+(frameCount));
  
  ellipse(frameCount,h ,300,20+(frameCount));
  triangle(frameCount,h ,300,20+(frameCount));

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: You don't need to call the `draw()` function yourself. It's automatically called 60 times per second. What exactly are you trying to do? Can you please post a [mcve]?

Comment: yes i will edit my original question.

Comment: When posting a snippet, please make sure to include the library. See the edit I just made.

Comment: Will do from now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(65);
  background('#ff0a0a'); 
  textSize(60);
  text("ART", 370, 250);
};

function mousePressed() {
  noFill();
  var red = random(100);
  var green = random(200);
  var blue =random(230);
  var h = random(height);

  stroke(red,green,blue);
  strokeWeight(8);
  rect(frameCount,h,300,20+(frameCount));
  
  ellipse(frameCount,h ,300,20+(frameCount));
  triangle(frameCount,h ,300,20+(frameCount));
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice thank you! Is there a way to make it so when i click once it will continuously draw, without having to click multiple times?

Comment: @codeneophyte Have you tried the 'mouseDragged()` function, or maybe checking whether the mouse is pressed from the `draw()` function?

Comment: No i wasn't aware of the 'mouseDragged' function, but I've tried it now and it does exactly what I want. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @codeneophyte No problem. I'd recommend reading through [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) whenever you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention another way and to address your question in [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259682/7575796) above, you can do something like this to draw continuously when the mouse is clicked once and stop when it is clicked again. This would work like a toggle switch for drawing :-

```js
var drawThings;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  frameRate(65);
  background('#ff0a0a');
  textSize(60);
  text("ART", 370, 250);
}

function draw() {
  if (drawThings) {
    noFill();
    var red = random(100);
    var green = random(200);
    var blue = random(230);
    var h = random(height);

    stroke(red, green, blue);
    strokeWeight(8);
    rect(frameCount, h, 300, 20 + (frameCount));

    ellipse(frameCount, h, 300, 20 + (frameCount));
    triangle(frameCount, h, 300, 20 + (frameCount));
  }
}

function mouseClicked() {
  drawThings = !drawThings;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.14/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would you not just use the `mouseIsPressed` variable? Note that I already explained this option in the comments.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Because that wouldn't achieve the toggle draw effect, that will give you the hold down to draw effect

Comment: I thought OP was looking for the holding down effect. Anyway, also note that you can shorten your `mouseClicked()` function to just be `drawThings = !drawThings;`

Comment: @KevinWorkman 1) The original question is indeed looking for hold down to draw effect, I was just addressing his question in the comments about how to start drawing on one mouse click and stop on another. 2) Nice catch, thanks for pointing out

Comment: Or maybe it is a bit ambiguous, the title says call draw on mouse click and not call draw while mouse is pressed.